# expression having type 'const CompareVPtrs' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call

Tags: c++, stl

I am implementing fifteen puzzle console game in C++, raises the following error

> ```
> Error 4  error C3848: expression having type 'const CompareVPtrs' would lose some
>    const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 
>    'bool CompareVPtrs::operator ()(Vertex *,Vertex *)'    
>    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xfunctional   
>   324 1  puzzle15
> ```

This is my structure

```
struct CompareVPtrs: public binary_function<Vertex*, Vertex*, bool>
{
    bool operator()( Vertex *lhs, Vertex *rhs)
    {
        return equal((int *)lhs->state, (int *)lhs->state+16,
            (int *)rhs->state);
    }
}
CompareVP;
```

The full game source code  https://gist.github.com/sunloverz/7338003

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It means your comparison operator needs to be `const`:

```
bool operator()( Vertex *lhs, Vertex *rhs) const
{ //                                       ^^^^^
  ....
}
```

Comment: It's even more interesting question why this error message appears only in Release (production) builds but not for Debug ones. (Had the same issue, just now.)

Comment: Encountered the same error message only in Release build. Placing the const keyword solved it, thanks! Funny thing is that the error message appears in VS2015 community but not in VS2010 (using different toolsets v140_xp in 2015 vs v100 in 2010 so that may be why).