# How to fix this C3848 error on vs2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++11

I'm trying to implement Best First Search using C++ on VS2013. Below is the code.

```
    //node for tree
    struct Node
    {
        Node(std::string const& s, std::string const& p)
            : state(s), path(p)
        {}

        const std::string state;
        const std::string path;
    };

    //heuristic functor
    struct ManhattanDistance
    {
        std::size_t operator()(std::string const& state, std::string const& goal)
        {
            std::size_t ret = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index != goal.size(); ++index)
            {
                if ('0' == state[index])
                    continue;

                auto digit = state[index] - '0';
                ret += abs(index / 3 - digit / 3) + abs(index % 3 - digit % 3);// distance(row) plus distance(col)
            }

            return ret;
        }
    };

    //functor to compare nodes using the heuristic function.
    template<typename HeuristicFunc>
    struct GreaterThan
    {
        explicit GreaterThan(HeuristicFunc h, std::string const& g = "012345678")
            : goal(g), heuristic(h)
        {}

        bool operator()(Node const& lhs, Node const& rhs) const
        {
            return heuristic(lhs.state, goal) > heuristic(rhs.state, goal);
            return true;
        }

        const std::string goal;
        const HeuristicFunc heuristic;
    };
```

When testing this code in Unit Test, compiler complained that :

> Error  1   error C3848: expression having type 'const ai::search::ManhattanDistance' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'size_t ManhattanDistance::operator ()(const std::string &,const std::string &)'

How to understand this error? How to fix it?

Comment: Don't you mean "Depth First Search" or "Breadth First Search"? "Best First Search" is new to me...

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt ,not DFS or BFS. Best First Search uses a heuristic function to evaluate each node, so that we can use this value as the key to order nodes in a priority queue. This way sometimes has better performance than plain DFS or BFS. Check here for more detail : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expression having type 'const CompareVPtrs' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816139/expression-having-type-const-comparevptrs-would-lose-some-const-volatile-quali)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your method `std::size_t ManhattanDistance::operator()(std::string const& state, std::string const& goal)` is not declared `const`, yet you try to call it on a `const ManhattanDistance` object.  The compiler is correctly rejecting this ill-formed program.

Change the defining line to declare the method `const`:

```
std::size_t operator()(std::string const& state, std::string const& goal) const
//                                                                        ^^^^^
```