# How do I fix errors in the standard MSVC libraries (xutility and xtool), which don't allow me to save?

Tags: c++, std

I'm using a Windows 10 computer and Visual Studio 2022. I'm trying to compile C++ code that was initially written on Linux in 2014. This required rebuilding the code from source files.

At this point, I've managed to solve every error in the codebase except for one, which says this:

```
Error C3848 expression having type 'const compit' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool compit::operator ()(const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &,const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)'
```

When I am compiling with a 'Debug' configuration, this error comes from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xutility` line 1528. The code block where this error is thrown is below:

```
template <class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    enable_if_t<is_same_v<_Remove_cvref_t<_Ty1>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty2>>, int> = 0>
constexpr bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr&& _Pred, _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) noexcept(
    noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right)) && noexcept(_Pred(_Right, _Left))) {   //ERROR ON THIS LINE
    // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering, when the arguments are the cv-same-type
    const auto _Result = static_cast<bool>(_Pred(_Left, _Right));
    if (_Result) {
        _STL_VERIFY(!_Pred(_Right, _Left), "invalid comparator");
    }

    return _Result;

}
```

If I change to a 'Release' build, the exact same error arises twice in the standard `xline` file instead of `xutility`, in the following code block:

```
    template <class _Keyty>
    bool _Lower_bound_duplicate(const _Nodeptr _Bound, const _Keyty& _Keyval) const {
        return !_Bound->_Isnil && !_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Getcomp(), _Keyval, _Traits::_Kfn(_Bound->_Myval));   //ERROR ON THIS LINE
    }

    template <class _Keyty>
    _Tree_find_result<_Nodeptr> _Find_lower_bound(const _Keyty& _Keyval) const {
        const auto _Scary = _Get_scary();
        _Tree_find_result<_Nodeptr> _Result{{_Scary->_Myhead->_Parent, _Tree_child::_Right}, _Scary->_Myhead};
        _Nodeptr _Trynode = _Result._Location._Parent;
        while (!_Trynode->_Isnil) {
            _Result._Location._Parent = _Trynode;
            if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Getcomp(), _Traits::_Kfn(_Trynode->_Myval), _Keyval)) { //ERROR ON THIS LINE
                _Result._Location._Child = _Tree_child::_Right;
                _Trynode                 = _Trynode->_Right;
            } else {
                _Result._Location._Child = _Tree_child::_Left;
                _Result._Bound           = _Trynode;
                _Trynode                 = _Trynode->_Left;
            }
        }

        return _Result;
    }
```

## Things I've Tried

[In this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816139/expression-having-type-const-comparevptrs-would-lose-some-const-volatile-quali), a similar error is thrown and the solution is to add const to the comparison operator. However, I can't edit a standard library file (it forces me to 'save as'). I've Ctrl+F'd my entire solution and didn't find any `std::_List_iterator` object, either.

[In this github forum](https://github.com/aiekick/ImGuiFontStudio/issues/5), a similar error was thrown due to an out-of-date 3rd party library. My code does use a legacy 3rd party Prosilica camera library, which was downloaded at https://www.alliedvision.com/en/support/software-downloads/. PvAPI.lib and PvAPI.h are included in the project settings. However, these files aren't mentioned in the error message, and I don't think I'm able to edit an external library like PvAPI.lib anyway.

What else can I try to solve this problem? I apologize if I've missed something obvious, as I'm relatively new to C++.

## Additional Info For Comments

Here is more of the error message, from the compiler output. I'm not 100% sure what is relevant, so I've posted most of it.

```
1>C:\<path>\stabiliser.cpp(261): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void TooN::IRLS<2,double,TooN::RobustI>::add_mJ<2,TooN::DefaultPrecision,TooN::Internal::VBase>(Precision,const TooN::Vector<2,Precision,TooN::Internal::VBase> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Precision=double
1>        ]
1>C:\<path>\stabiliser.cpp(261): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void TooN::IRLS<2,double,TooN::RobustI>::add_mJ<2,TooN::DefaultPrecision,TooN::Internal::VBase>(Precision,const TooN::Vector<2,Precision,TooN::Internal::VBase> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Precision=double
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xutility(1528,1): error C3848: expression having type 'const compit' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool compit::operator ()(const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &,const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xutility(1527): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::_Debug_lt_pred<const compit&,const _Kty&,const _Keyty&,0>(_Pr,_Ty1,_Ty2) noexcept(<expr>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Keyty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=const compit &,
1>            _Ty1=const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>> &,
1>            _Ty2=const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>> &
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree(1353): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_find_result<std::_Tree_node<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *> std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Find_lower_bound<_Other>(const _Keyty &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Other=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Keyty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree(1353): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_find_result<std::_Tree_node<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *> std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Find_lower_bound<_Other>(const _Keyty &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Other=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Keyty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree(1363): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Find<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>(const _Other &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Other=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree(1363): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::_Find<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>(const _Other &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Other=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xtree(1362): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::find(const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\<path>\stabiliser.cpp(458): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::find(const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain,
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\set(52): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>,
1>            _Pr=compit,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Chain>>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\<path>\stabiliser.h(82): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::set<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,compit,std::allocator<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Chain
1>        ]
1>system.cpp
```

The first message is concerning stabiliser.cc line 260. The relevant code block is below:

```
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 6; iteration++) {
        irls.clear();
        ImageRef pixel_offset = ir_rounded(this_offset + offset);
        Vector<2> offset_error = vec(pixel_offset) - (this_offset + offset);

        for (int i = 0; i < num_trackers; i++) {
            double movement = vessel_edgels[i].best_match(im, pixel_offset);
            if (movement != VesselEdge::not_found) {
                irls.add_mJ(movement, vessel_edgels[i].my_direction); /// ERROR HERE
            }
        }
        irls.compute();
        this_offset += irls.get_mu() + offset_error;
    }
```

Apparently, `vessel_edgels[i].my_direction` is not `const` and needs to be, since the template I get by CTRL+clicking `add_mj` is

```
inline void add_mJ(Precision m, const Vector<Size2,Precision2,Base2>& J)
```

I've tried adding `const` to the definition of `my_direction`, but the variable is changed in another file, so it throws an error. I also tried defining a temporary constant variable, like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < num_trackers; i++) {
            double movement = vessel_edgels[i].best_match(im, pixel_offset);
            if (movement != VesselEdge::not_found) {
                const TooN::Vector<2> temp = vessel_edgels[i].my_direction; //ADDED THIS LINE
                irls.add_mJ(movement, temp);
            }
        }
```

But that didn't change the error message from the Output of the compiler, which still referred to line 261 of stabiliser.cc.

I'll keep working on this; a lot to google. Thank you for the help in the comments so far. What is stack overflow etiquette at this point? Should I delete the question, or post any solution I find?

Comment: The error is more likely to be in *your* code, not in the system headers.

Comment: The error is neither in `xutility` nor in `xtool`. That is merely where the error is *reported*, because those pieces of code check invariants that are violated elsewhere by the caller. To find where the actual error is you need to look at the *entire* error message, not just the top line. You will find the call trace that leads to the error being produced, and somewhere in this trace is the cause of the error (in *your* code), not the standard library implementation.

Comment: Please show the code that calls the code that you think is buggy. It's highly likely that code is what is actually buggy. Without that we cannot help you. Stdlib code gets abused in the worst possible manner by developers and as such tends to be pretty well debugged (with some exceptions that are documented but require ABI breaks to fix), you're not using anything suspect. So odds are it's the code calling this. That code is not part of the stdlib.

Comment: You may find errors in the Standard Library implementation or in build tools themselves, but these are vanishingly rare. Unless you frequently dive into the darker, less traveled regions of a language, you will find only a couple such mistakes in a decades-long career. And if you do find one, what are you going to do about it other than submit a bug report and look for a work-around? Editing the library files can have unforeseen results, and an update may well dump the bug back in your lap. Change compilers? A political impossibility on many projects.

Comment: Reading error messages takes a great deal of practice. That snippet from the error message reports where the error was detected. But the message was much longer; it gave a list of the various function calls that led to that one. Work you way back through that list (or start at the other end and work your way forward) and figure out what in your code is leading to that error.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I'm just trying to figure out how to view the 'entire error message', or the 'call trace', one second please...

Comment: If you are not already, take a look at the Output tab, usually located beside the Error List. The Error list provides an executive summary and removes information to keep the list short. The Output tab shows you everything the VS compiler has got, and the reams of information can be intimidating. We can help with that.

Comment: Other tricks include isolating the error (use [mre] as inspiration) because the less room a mistake has to hide, the easier it is to figure out, and using different compilers to see if they give better diagnostics. [Matt Goldbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is an exceptional tool to help see what other compilers do with your code.

Comment: The issue is that the `compit::operator ()` overload mentioned in the message is not `const`, but it should be.

Comment: Just writing an edit to the main question, one moment please

Comment: @ThomasL *However, I can't edit a standard library file* -- Even if you could edit them, do not do this.  Editing header files basically corrupts your installation of the compiler.  The people who do edit system header files are ones who know exactly what they're doing, why they're doing it, know C++ at a super-advanced level, and hopefully reported the issue to the compiler vendors so that they can implement the change(s) in a future release of the compiler.

Comment: An object can be viewed through a `const` lens when assigned to a `const` reference without any work on your part. In this context `const` is a promise that the object will not be changed through the reference. Add `compit::operator ()` to the question as it, not just `vessel_edgels[i].my_direction` seems to be at the ecenter of the problem. Also consider making a [mre] to help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this error by CTRL+F'ing my solution for `compit`, and then I added 'const':

```
struct compit {
    bool operator() (const std::list<Chain>::iterator& it1, const std::list<Chain>::iterator& it2) const { //ADDED CONST HERE
        return (&(*it1) < &(*it2));
    }
};
```

Very similar to [this stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816139/expression-having-type-const-comparevptrs-would-lose-some-const-volatile-quali), I just incorrectly assumed that 'compit' was part of the standard library, while it was really a part of my code.